# 403 Forbidden on file placed at /var/www/html when attempting to download?

Tags: download, apache-http-server, centos

I am trying to copy a file from my server to my desktop computer.  I placed it in `/var/www/html` (where the web pages are) and when I try to download it I get `403 Forbidden`. I even tried `chmod 777` on the file and it doesn't fix it.

What am I doing wrong and why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to modify the file so that it is owned by the Apache user.  By default, Apache will run as the `www-data` user (found in the `www-data` group).  You can use `chown` to modify the file's owner (may have to be used with `sudo`):

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html
```

Finally, you need to ensure the files have at *least* read and execute permissions for the Apache user.  You've already done this, as you said, but after modifying all the permissions/file owners, you should ensure everything's okay by running  `ls -l /var/www/html`.  As a security measure, it's also wise to remove all permissions for other users:

```
chmod -R 0550 /var/www/html
```

Note that if you use PHP or another scripting language which requires write access, you may have to modify the permission mask above to `0770` instead.  As a precaution, only use that mask on directories where required (e.g. to write website cache data, or upload files)

Comment: chown: 'www-data:www-data' invalid user

Comment: also tried apache as the user and it didn't give an error but I still can't download the file (403)

Comment: @Ryan you need to check your `httpd.conf` or `apache2.conf` files to see what the actual Apache username is.

Comment: Ok, will do. Is it also possible that the file types have different permissions too? Because I can browse rich html pages with images and such on the same paths.

Comment: @Ryan check using `ls -l` who owns those files, and what permissions they have.  Are you attempting to access a raw HTML file, or some kind of dynamic page (i.e. PHP/Python/Ruby)?  Also, make sure you didn't set any kind of blocking rules in your `.htaccess`, `httpd.conf`, or site configuration files.

Comment: It's a .zip file, I'll look into those things, thanks.

Comment: On OS X the user group is `_www`. So you would do `chown -R _www /var/www/html`

Answer (score 5):

I'm using CentOS 7 + Apache, the only command that resolved my issue is it (because I tried chown+chmod before):

> sudo setenforce 0 #disable SELinux

And then, I can download the file (in my case, anyfile.zip), but, it can open the doors for attackers write and execute code.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have [SELinux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux) enabled.  Simplest way around it for the current purpose is to chown the file in question to the user ID Apache is running as.